# Save to distributed file system from worker processes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am quite new with pyspark. In my application with pyspark, I want to achieve following things:

1. Create a RDD using python list and partition it into some partitions.
2. Now use rdd.mapPartitions(func)
3. Here, the function "func" performs an iterative operation which, reads content of saved file into a local variable (for e.g. numpy array), performs some updates using the rdd partion data and again saves the content of variable to some common file system.

I am not able to figure out how to read and write a variable inside a worker process which is accessible to all processes??

Comment: You may need broadcast variables and accumulators or their combination. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shared-variables.

Comment: Hi Jacek, I am aware of broadcast variable and accumulator functionality, but I want the result to be saved to shared file as soon as the partition has finished updating the parameters. So that the updates should be available to other workers and they don't have to wait for all workers to finish. This workflow is not possible with broadcast or accumulators.